# How to identify the email which i got from black-berry / iphone / ipad?

Tags: java, iphone, blackberry, ipad, jakarta-mail

I want to know the mobile phone name(blackberry/iPhone/ipad) from which mobile I got email. How to identify the mobile name ? Are there any headers to identify the mobile name ?

Comment: Why do you need this exactly?

Comment: In my requirement I have to find out from which medium message is coming. either black berry/iPhone/ipad. Can you please suggest me How to identify from which mobile I got the email?

Answer (score 6):

No, there are not. Any old app on any old phone can send an email with any headers it likes. There is nothing you can rely upon to always be there.

Comment: Can we change predefined "User-Agent" header in mobile browsers ?

Comment: What does the User-Agent have to do with this question? If it doesn't then it should be a entirely separate question and not just a comment.